# Correct UML semantics and syntax

Tags: uml

I have 2 UML classes that are named owner and followed by vehicle.

I am wanting to know whether I can state that vehicle 'generalizes' owner as I would like the object vehicle to inherit attributes assigned to owner. It doesn't seem right as I wouldn't consider vehicle a subclass or subtype of owner but seeing I am new to UML, I'm no expert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said, "vehicle 'generalizes' owner", but then said, "I would like the object vehicle to inherit attributes assigned to owner." Those two statements are contradictory because a superclass *generalizes* and a subclass *specializes*. Since you want Vehicle to inherit attributes from Owner, I'll assume you are asking whether you can state that Owner *generalizes* Vehicle (and Vehicle *specializes* Owner).

**In the real world, it is *not* a true statement that every Vehicle is always a kind of Owner.** What does your Car own? Do you mean that it "owns" its engine, wheels, and doors? Is that the same concept as "owning" your car or your home?

Classes are meant to represent more than buckets of reusable attributes and methods that allow you to seemingly save some coding time--although many programmers treat them as such. They are called *classes* because they represent classes of things in the *problem domain* (i.e., the "real world"). This is where many programmers go astray--they focus on things in the *solution domain*, which change much more rapidly, and they lose all the benefits of object orientation. One of the key tenets of OOA / OOP is that the problem domain changes infrequently, so it provides a relatively stable base upon which to build software. If you claim strange things, such as "a Vehicle is always a kind of Owner", you build on unstable sand and may spend lots of time fighting the tide later, when you find a case where the claim is not so convenient anymore. **In what way is a Vehicle *always* an Owner? Would many business-oriented subject matter experts agree with you?**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Forgive my n00bness. I understand that if I were to say that Owner generalizes Vehicle and Vehicle specializes the Owner, that it be incorrect to say that Vehicle is a kind of Owner as I am trying to express the ownership of a vehicle e.g. Bob owns a Ford. I am however unsure how I can represent what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I think I would model a `Person` that plays the role of `AssetOwner`, and a `Vehicle` that plays the role of an `Asset`. You could then wire them up with associations. (Start with English statements, like "an `Asset` is owned by one `AssetOwner` / an `AssetOwner` owns any number of `Assets`.) That's hard to show you in this tiny comment box. I suggest you start with Leon Starr's excellent article, [Articulate Class Models](http://www.uml.org/HTB_Articulate_Class_Models_OMG.pdf), which has lots of great examples.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a common abstract class to regroup common attributes. Let say you want *Owner* and *Vehicle* to share a common *name* attribute. You could use the following model.

[UML common attributes http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/commonAttributes.jpg](http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/commonAttributes.jpg)

Comment: Thanks Xaelis. That appears to make sense although am unsure because of my lack of experience and knowledge in UML whether it is the right way. What else would I have to consider to validate and verify the model? Is there a way I can validate and verify the model?

Comment: There is no magic to validate or verify a model. The big question is "Is the model tells what you want to say?". But the first step is to use a real modeling tool not a drawing tool.

Comment: To be honest I don't know because the more I try and learn about it the more I learn that my view of a model is biased and it is extremely difficult to take the view of an "outsider". I am using a proper modelling tool. Hmm, is there a way I can get the help of a maven who can guide me and correct my mistakes, question my designs, etc?